# How to write if statement on model.property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

For the following 'if' statement I am getting an error:
"the name model does not exist in the current context".

```
    @if (model.OrderStatusId == 1)
      {

      }
```

This line not shows an error:

```
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderStatusId)
```

What would be right syntax for the 'if' statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement, `Model` is a property of your `View`. Notice the uppercase **M**.

```
@if (Model.OrderStatusId == 1)
{

}
```

Here, `model` is an part of an expression method argument and can be named anything you want.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderStatusId)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@if (Model.OrderStatusId == 1)
      {

      }
```

Uppercase M on Model

Answer (score 2):

you need an to use an uppercase `M` for this to work

`Model`